How do I create separate fields for normal users and admins users in Django?
I have a custom user model that has fields common for both a normal user and an admin (which are email[used to log into the system], first name, and last name). But I want to give additional fields for the normal users of the system. How do I achieve this?
Ii tried the above code but it only create a one single table for both normal users and admins

Ii tried the above code but it only create a one single table for both normal users and admins     obviously you only have one model. That's why. UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager) is not a model. It's a model manager, as name says.


I tried the above code but it only create a one single table for both normal users and admins.

That makes sense, it does not create two separate tables, it just adds a column is_staff that is True for staff users, and False for non-staff users.
You can then protect a view for example with the @staff_member_required decorator:
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required


@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    # …
    pass
While you can make a separate table for non-admin users, I would strongly advise not to do this: it complicates the login system as well as registering users.
If you really want a separate table, you could make a Profile model and let the UserAccount refer to a Profile, but I think this only complicates the matter.
Why not just keep one simple table where the admins don't (have to) fill in additional data. This is simpler.

You can add a user_type field on your model. I can make you an example:
USER_TYPE_DATA = (
("admin", "admin"),
("member", "member"),)

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPE_DATA, default="member") #new field here
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', 


    upload_to='profilePictures', null=True, blank=True)
    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
         return self.email + " | " + self.first_name

Then you can check if the user_type equals whatever you want or need and that's it.

Thank you for your answer. But how can I add new fields specifically for the user_type = Member? New fields like
employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=255) and
work_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

You can set those fields as blank=True, null=True
So you can save those fields only for the users you choose you want to use those fields
